# Database structure for multi-level category (Best Approach)

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

The approach this user made on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078074/mysql-multi-level-category-structure) for the database structure works fine. However, thinking in a relational database approach, what is the best approach for a multi-level category database?

Comment: Can a sub-category belong to one parent category or more than one? Also, MySQL isn't great for hierarchical data. Do you have other options?

Comment: I want to build something like the facebook FAQ: https://www.facebook.com/help/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**VERY SIMPLE AND EFFECTIVE**

We simply do a [recursive association](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php).

```
id       title        content       parent_id
==============================================
1        item1         NULL         NULL     
2        item2         NULL         1          
3        item3         abcd         2       
4        item4         efgh         2
```

In this example:

`item1` is the first level (see that the `parent_id` is `NULL`).

`item2` is a second level option from `item1` (see that the `parent_id` is `1` and the `content` is `NULL` making this another drill down option only).

`item3` and `item4` are content from `item2` (see that `parent_id` is `2` and the `content` is NOT null).